# Open directory under the cursor in other pane in vifm

Tags: shortcut, vifm

Is there any shortcut in vifm to open the directory currently marked by the cursor in the second pane? and possibly switch to the other pane as well?

Comment: http://q2a.vifm.info/64/how-can-i-open-current-directory-in-other-pane

Comment: Thanks glider, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `:cd` command can receive two arguments, first for the current pane and second for inactive one (as described in [this section of manual](https://vifm.info/manual.shtml#Commands)). This way you can open directory under cursor in other pane with the following command:

```
:cd %d %c
```

...where `%d` is a macro for current directory and `%c` is macro for file/directory under cursor (see [vifm command macros](https://vifm.info/manual.shtml#Command%20macros)). Or with a single `sync` command:

```
:sync %c
```

You can map it to some key or sequence in your `vifmrc` (with `<Tab>` at the end for automatic pane switching):

```
nnoremap zo :sync %c<CR><Tab>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do:

```
cd!
```

this opens the same dir in both panes. try:

```
cd! /opt
```